# Entity Framework object missing related data

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I have an Entity Framework model that has two tables, client and postcode. Postcode can have many clients, client can have 1 postcode. They are joined on the postcode.
The two tables are mapped to views.

I have some clients that do not have a Postcode in the model, however in the DB they do!

I ran some tests and found postcodes that were returning clients when I do `Postcode.Clients` but not all of the clients? In the db a postcode had 14 related clients but EF was only returning the first 6. Basically certain postcodes are not returning all the data.

Lazy loading is turned on and I have tried turning it off without any luck.

Any ideas?

I am using VS 2010, C#, .NET 4.0, EF4 and SQL Server 2008

Thanks

UPDATE:

I have been running through this in LinqPad. I try the following code

```
Client c = Clients.Where(a => a.ClientId == 9063202).SingleOrDefault();
c.PostcodeView.Dump();
```

This returns null.

I then take the generated SQL and run this in a separate SQL query and it works correctly (after I add the @ to the start of the variable name)

```
SELECT TOP (2) 
[Extent1].[ClientId] AS [ClientId], 
[Extent1].[Surname] AS [Surname], 
[Extent1].[Forename] AS [Forename], 
[Extent1].[FlatNo] AS [FlatNo], 
[Extent1].[StNo] AS [StNo], 
[Extent1].[Street] AS [Street], 
[Extent1].[Town] AS [Town], 
[Extent1].[Postcode] AS [Postcode]
FROM (SELECT 
      [ClientView].[ClientId] AS [ClientId], 
      [ClientView].[Surname] AS [Surname], 
      [ClientView].[Forename] AS [Forename], 
      [ClientView].[FlatNo] AS [FlatNo], 
      [ClientView].[StNo] AS [StNo], 
      [ClientView].[Street] AS [Street], 
      [ClientView].[Town] AS [Town], 
      [ClientView].[Postcode] AS [Postcode]
      FROM [dbo].[ClientView] AS [ClientView]) AS [Extent1]
WHERE 9063202 = [Extent1].[ClientId]
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @EntityKeyValue1 VarChar(8) = 'G15 6NB'
-- EndRegion
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Postcode] AS [Postcode], 
[Extent1].[ltAstId] AS [ltAstId], 
[Extent1].[ltLhoId] AS [ltLhoId], 
[Extent1].[ltChcpId] AS [ltChcpId], 
[Extent1].[ltCppId] AS [ltCppId], 
[Extent1].[ltWardId] AS [ltWardId], 
[Extent1].[ltAst] AS [ltAst], 
[Extent1].[ltCpp] AS [ltCpp], 
[Extent1].[ltWard] AS [ltWard], 
[Extent1].[WardNo] AS [WardNo], 
[Extent1].[Councillor] AS [Councillor], 
[Extent1].[ltAdminCentre] AS [ltAdminCentre], 
[Extent1].[ltChcp] AS [ltChcp], 
[Extent1].[Forename] AS [Forename], 
[Extent1].[Surname] AS [Surname], 
[Extent1].[AreaNo] AS [AreaNo], 
[Extent1].[LtAomId] AS [LtAomId], 
[Extent1].[OOHltCoordinatorId] AS [OOHltCoordinatorId], 
[Extent1].[OvernightltCoordinatorId] AS [OvernightltCoordinatorId], 
[Extent1].[DayltCoordinatorId] AS [DayltCoordinatorId]
FROM (SELECT 
      [PostcodeView].[Postcode] AS [Postcode], 
      [PostcodeView].[ltAstId] AS [ltAstId], 
      [PostcodeView].[ltLhoId] AS [ltLhoId], 
      [PostcodeView].[ltChcpId] AS [ltChcpId], 
      [PostcodeView].[ltCppId] AS [ltCppId], 
      [PostcodeView].[ltWardId] AS [ltWardId], 
      [PostcodeView].[ltAst] AS [ltAst], 
      [PostcodeView].[ltCpp] AS [ltCpp], 
      [PostcodeView].[ltWard] AS [ltWard], 
      [PostcodeView].[WardNo] AS [WardNo], 
      [PostcodeView].[Councillor] AS [Councillor], 
      [PostcodeView].[ltAdminCentre] AS [ltAdminCentre], 
      [PostcodeView].[ltChcp] AS [ltChcp], 
      [PostcodeView].[Forename] AS [Forename], 
      [PostcodeView].[Surname] AS [Surname], 
      [PostcodeView].[AreaNo] AS [AreaNo], 
      [PostcodeView].[LtAomId] AS [LtAomId], 
      [PostcodeView].[DayltCoordinatorId] AS [DayltCoordinatorId], 
      [PostcodeView].[OOHltCoordinatorId] AS [OOHltCoordinatorId], 
      [PostcodeView].[OvernightltCoordinatorId] AS [OvernightltCoordinatorId]
      FROM [dbo].[PostcodeView] AS [PostcodeView]) AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Postcode] = @EntityKeyValue1
```

Comment: Showing some code could be helpful.

Comment: i don't know what your asking here - but have you tried eager loading: `Client c = Clients.Include("Postcode").Where(a => a.ClientId == 9063202).SingleOrDefault();` btw - you can use the predicate in the `SingleOrDefault` method - you don't need the Where method.

Comment: @RPM1984 - i think the problem here lies with the fact that the SQL statement generated by the entity framework returns different results when run directly in sql opposed to what happens when using the association to get access to clients and postcodes

Comment: Have tried using Load() and Include with no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up removing the relationship and manually getting child data.
Nasty but cannot find a reason why this is happening. Cheers for the comments